# Google Analytics - send data to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have recently been given a project requirement to send data over to google analytics from a certain page. I have no clue how to do that.

Account Id and every thing has already been created, I just want to know how  I could send data on load of a certain webpage.
I have been looking up google analytics from what I understood I think I need to first push into ga functions the analytics tacking id and I think I need to have pageview as the event.
Could someone please share tutorial links for this?

Regards,
Farhan

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking for the Event Tracking with the Google Analytics as page Tracking is Quite Simple you just need to add the tracking code and page Tracking is done so check out the below link and code you will find how you can do the Event Tracking

[Send custom Event to Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

```
ga('send', {
   hitType: 'event',
   eventCategory: 'Videos',
   eventAction: 'play',
   eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign'
});
```

Comment: I am looking for page tracking but I need to send some custom data along with it. Could you please share a sample code snippet of how I could send the data?
And also could you please let me know if I am correct in setting up the account..
ga.push(['_setAccount', googleAnalyticsTrackingId]);
ga.push(['_trackPageview']);

Comment: @Farhan can you provide more detail about what short of custom data you wanted to send along with the Page Tracking that will be help me to understand your scenario in better way.

Comment: I have to pass users data - ip, region etc and also a few search params for eg. order number. 
I apologize for the inconvienience, but I just came to know that I need to set up this using a google tag manager.

Comment: i guess in that case you might wanted to take a look over the examples here https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide